# How do I use aplay and arecord to capture audio from the sound card line-in and then directly stream it to line-out?

Tags: audio, raspbian, alsa

I'm working with a Raspberry Pi hat sound card that has ADC and DAC with RCA line-in and line-out. I'm running Raspbian on the Pi.

I'm attempting to capture data from ADC and pipe it directly to the DAC so that I can implement filters in between in the future.

I know it is possible to use arecord to capture data and save to a wav file and then use aplay to play the audio file. However, I haven't been able to figure out how to skip saving to a file and stream the data directly.

Any suggestions is appreciated. If this doesn't belong here please point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: I've never tried it, but I think you're looking for `alsaloop`, or something like `arecord | aplay`